# In CDS View select statement, how to convert type DEC to type INT?

Tags: data-conversion, netweaver, cds

In a CDS View select statement, given that I have a column of type `DEC`, how do I convert that to type `INT`?

**Work done so far:** According to the [`CAST_EXPR` documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abencds_f1_cast_expression.htm), this is not possible with `CAST_EXPR` . According to the [numeric functions documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abencds_f1_sql_functions_numeric.htm), math functions like `FLOOR` will return a value of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** the [numeric functions documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abencds_f1_sql_functions_numeric.htm) is correct.

The code `floor(fieldname)` will convert a `DEC(X,Y)` (where `Y > 0`) into a `DEC(X,0)`. Essentially, `floor` strips the decimal places from the field without changing its type.

On the other hand, `ceil(fieldname)` will round up to the nearest integer *and* convert a `DEC` to an `INT`

If you want to get an integer from the `floor` function, then you must call `ceil(floor(fieldname))`

On a NetWeaver system, you should be able to find the CDS View `demo_cds_sql_functions_num` and program/report `demo_cds_sql_functions_num` that help demonstrate these concepts. You can use the debugger to view the report's variable `result` and confirm my findings.

Comment: `floor(fieldname)` converts your DEC(x,y) to a DEC(x,**0**), which converts fine to ABAP's integers, but is not exactly the same.

Comment: You can see the exact type by inspecting the SQL view that's generated from the CDS, see annotation `@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName`.

Comment: @Florian I just tested and `floor` and `ceil` seem to convert to type `abap.int4` This makes sense, since `cast` cannot be used to convert a `DEC` to an `INT`. I suppose the writers of `cast` wanted the caller to explicitly decide if they wanted a floor or ceiling function.

Comment: Agree. Didn't notice they produce INTs directly.

Comment: @Florian it seems that I was wrong and you are correct. I just confirmed with a more complete demo and discussion with the responsible technical writer

Answer (score 1):

`ceil` does it:

```
cast(ceil(fieldname) as abap.int4)
```

Note that `floor` won't.

Comment: Can you please explain why it doesn't work for `floor`, and why a `cast` would be required?

Comment: your suggested code gives a warning: `CAST CAST( CEIL( "HOURLY"."... to identical type INT4`

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work for `floor`, but `cast(floor(risk_value) as abap.int4)` refuses to compile with `CAST ... of type CURR to INT4 is not possible`. Looks like a surprising case of type preference.